# Keycloak cannot connect to LDAP

Tags: jboss, ldap, wildfly, keycloak

I'm trying to connect my keyclak (docker-based) installation to LDAP. To test ldap, I logged into docker container and issued the following query:

`ldapwhoami -vvv -h ldap.domain.com -p 389 -D ldap_srv_user -x -w password`

Which successfully returned a success with:

`ldap_initialize( ldap://ldap.domain.com:389 )
u:GLB\ldap_srv_user
Result: Success (0)`

However, when I enter same connect url (`ldap://ldap.domain.com:389`) in keycloak LDAP federation config I get a connection refused with the following stacktrace:

> 11:27:15,578 ERROR [org.keycloak.services] (default task-39)
>   KC-SERVICES0055: Error when connecting to LDAP:
>   ldap.domain.com:389: javax.naming.CommunicationException:
>   ldap.domain.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused (Connection refused)]  at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.(Connection.java:226)  at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.(LdapClient.java:137)  at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1615)    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2749)  at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.(LdapCtx.java:319)    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192)
>     at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210)
>     at
>   .....

Did anyone also had this issue? What could be the reason?

Comment: I have not encountered this error when running Keycloak. However, have you tried other lower-level tests such as `telnet` and `nc`? These are the most reliable tools I have used (and `openssl` for `ldaps` connections) to establish LDAP connections. Also try to use [kcadm](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#connect-to-ldap-over-ssl) as per Keycloak documentation.

Comment: Hallo @Niemand! Have you found a solution to this in the meanwhile? I'm also encountering this issue 2 years after you've asked this and still no answer has been submitted!

Comment: Hi @roxch, hardly remember the problem by now, but I think the workaround I've applied was putting an IP address directly instead of a hostname.